# how can we use the coordinates of an image

Tags: iphone, xcode, random, uiimageview, coordinates

I'm on xcode And I have an image that is created everytime we open the application, I want to use its coordinates to calculate some stuff. But I don't know how can I use them, I think that it is something like

```
CGPoint(x;y)
```

or

```
int x = (x of the image)
```

and

```
int y= (y of theimage).
```

How can i do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the origin of a UIImageView, just use:

```
int x = imageView.frame.origin.x;
int y = imageView.frame.origin.y;
```

Or:

```
CGPoint origin = imageView.frame.origin;
```